# how i can set transform by using raphael lib

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am using raphael lib for but when i open my svg file it has following code and there is no way to set these params if i put path without it map is not show.

```
<g transform="translate(0.000000,524.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
```

Comment: Please add your raphael code as an edit to the original question. (Comments have a character limit--they're really only good for short answers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raphaël doesn't support <g> elements, but there's a related concept called [sets](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.set). However these sets aren't actually represented in the DOM.

I think your question is probably "How do I import my existing SVG files into Raphaël". Have you tried searching for answers along those lines? A quick search shows e.g [Raphael JS - Use a SVG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926643/raphael-js-use-a-svg-file).

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly what you need to do is parse out the contents of the transform attribute and call [Element.translate](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.translate) for the translate and [Element.scale](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.scale) for the scale.

Comment: thanks for reply,  I read out that convert your image in svg format and then get d value from it and then put it in path variable of js. I did the same but my map is not showing, but if i put <g> tag direct by ff debuger it shows. Please let me know what i need to do

Comment: I can't follow what you are saying, can you give me a jsfiddle?

Comment: <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="587.000000pt" height="524.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 587.000000 524.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.10, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2011
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,524.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="..."