# raphael icons extract path

Tags: svg, raphael

I am trying to create some login buttons based on the RaphaelJs icons, but on the example page there is only the Twitter paths that are available!

So I am looking to understand how to extract the SVG paths from Inkscape and update the example on http://jsfiddle.net/aqoon/LN23r/5/ for Google using http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Google_free_icon.svg file

```
var facebookBtn = "",
    googleBtn = "M47.446122,148.46699L47.463496,149.0968L47.430196,149.09969C47.363594,148.8854247.278172,148.7259147.173az931,148.62119C47.069686,148.5164646.943725,148.464146.796048,148.4641C46.681186,148.464146.582493,148.4875146.499968,148.53432C46.417441,148.5811346.340465,148.6571446.269039,148.76235C46.124256,148.9775946.051865,149.2237246.051865,149.50074C46.051865,149.6329846.069239,149.7577346.103987,149.875C46.138734,149.9922846.189408,150.095846.256009,150.18556C46.385347,150.359346.54316,150.4461746.729448,150.44617C46.802803,150.4461746.871816,150.4307346.936487,150.39984C47.001155,150.3689547.054242,150.3264847.095748,150.27243C47.152694,150.1971547.181168,150.1078647.18117,150.00458C47.181168,149.9090347.155349,149.8400247.103711,149.79755C47.05207,149.7550846.96689,149.7338446.84817,149.73384L46.84817,149.70054L47.771883,149.70054L47.771883,149.73384C47.686942,149.7415647.62734,149.7533947.593076,149.76931C47.558809,149.7852447.533472,149.8125147.517065,149.85111C47.498724,149.8935947.489555,149.9780447.489557,150.10448C47.489555,150.1392347.491485,150.1932847.495348,150.26664L47.498244,150.29994C47.461564,150.2864347.434538,150.2796747.417165,150.27967C47.395929,150.2796747.368903,150.2907747.336087,150.31297C47.252112,150.3708847.154625,150.4152847.043626,150.44617C46.932625,150.4770646.815351,150.492546.691804,150.4925C46.521925,150.492546.368697,150.4635546.23212,150.40563C46.095541,150.3477245.984782,150.2647145.899844,150.15661C45.836139,150.0755345.787154,149.9790145.752889,149.86704C45.718624,149.7550845.701491,149.6363545.701491,149.51088C45.701491,149.338145.732378,149.1773945.794152,149.02875C45.855926,148.8801145.942795,148.7575346.054761,148.661C46.146456,148.5828246.252147,148.5224946.371835,148.48002C46.491521,148.4375646.617964,148.4163246.751165,148.41632C46.828382,148.4163246.900049,148.4235646.966168,148.43804C47.032284,148.4525247.102503,148.4761647.176826,148.50898L47.262248,148.54807C47.283481,148.5567647.302785,148.561147.320161,148.5611C47.358768,148.561147.388207,148.5297347.408479,148.46699L47.446122,148.46699z",
    twitterBtn = "M14.605,13.11c0.913-2.851,2.029-4.698,3.313-6.038c0.959-1,1.453-1.316,0.891-0.216c0.25-0.199,0.606-0.464,0.885-0.605c1.555-0.733,1.442-0.119,0.373,0.54c2.923-1.045,2.82,0.286-0.271,0.949c2.527,0.047,5.214,1.656,5.987,5.077c0.105,0.474-0.021,0.428,0.464,0.514c1.047,0.186,2.03,0.174,2.991-0.13c-0.104,0.708-1.039,1.167-2.497,1.471c-0.541,0.112-0.651,0.083-0.005,0.229c0.799,0.179,1.69,0.226,2.634,0.182c-0.734,0.846-1.905,1.278-3.354,1.296c-0.904,3.309-2.976,5.678-5.596,7.164c-6.152,3.492-15.108,2.984-19.599-3.359c2.947,2.312,7.312,2.821,10.555-0.401c-2.125,0-2.674-1.591-0.99-2.449c-1.595-0.017-2.608-0.521-3.203-1.434c-0.226-0.347-0.229-0.374,0.14-0.64c0.405-0.293,0.958-0.423,1.528-0.467c-1.651-0.473-2.66-1.335-3.009-2.491c-0.116-0.382-0.134-0.363,0.256-0.462c0.38-0.097,0.87-0.148,1.309-0.17C6.11,10.88,5.336,9.917,5.139,8.852c-0.186-1.006,0.005-0.748,0.758-0.46C9.263,9.68,12.619,11.062,14.605,13.11L14.605,13.11z",
    yahooBtn = "";

$('.twitterBtn').each(function(i) {
    paper = Raphael($(this)[0], 40, 40)
    paper.path(twitterBtn).attr({
        "fill": "#333"
    })
})
$('.googleBtn').each(function(i) {
    paper = Raphael($(this)[0], 40, 40)
    paper.path(googleBtn).attr({
        "fill": "#333"
    })
})​
```

I tried to strip the SVG file so that I just have one layer and only the 'G' but on the http://jsfiddle.net/aqoon/LN23r/5/ is not being displayed, what am i missing?

Also how do i add extra layers to the var googleBtn, as when I open the http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Google_free_icon.svg in Inkscape there are many layers and paths?

Comment: it needs more than 40x40 space without scaling, since the coordinates are on the scale of 200

Comment: ok i see, but how do i add all the 'd' path elements from http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Google_free_icon.svg to the var googleBtn, as this has many layers?

Comment: I gather you'll need more than one path there.

Comment: yes, but how do i do this on the above example?

Comment: Raphael does not support (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135061/svg-files-in-raphael-can-they-be-used) loading whole SVG images and using those as paths, so the only reasonable option here is to extract separate paths and store them in some sort of datastructure, like in the example with the tiger (http://raphaeljs.com/tiger.html) -- check the source code there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raphael does not support ( [SVG files in Raphael, can they be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135061/)… ) loading whole SVG images and using those as paths, so the only reasonable option here is to extract separate paths and store them in some sort of datastructure, like in the example with the tiger ( http://raphaeljs.com/tiger.html ) -- check the source code there.

The SVG files can also have rather strange internal coordinate system, so it pays to adjust the view box after loading one, like this

```
    var path = paper.path(googleBtn).attr({
        "fill": "#333"
    });
    var bbox = path.getBBox();
    paper.setViewBox(bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height);
```

To group different elements, one can use Raphael.Set http://jsfiddle.net/LN23r/40/

```
    var shadow = paper.path(googleBtn).attr({"fill": "#0F0", "stroke":"none"}).translate(0.08,0.08);
    var path = paper.path(googleBtn).attr({"fill": "#333", "stroke":"none"});
    var set = paper.set(shadow, path);
    var bbox = set.getBBox();
    paper.setViewBox(bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height);
```

When grouping elements, note that they have transformation matrices associated with them in the SVG file (e.g. transform="matrix(204.67566,0,0,204.67566,-9225.9642,-30242.949)"), which affects the respective position and scale of the elements.

On the whole, the process of porting paths from SVG is not entirely trivial, but manageable. There is also a plugin that may help you with this, see https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import

Comment: thanks for this, but i have one more question / clarification: what you have done is to use the same 'G' path data and have translate(0.08,0.08) - i understand this, but how do i say for example group the other elements - it seems the issue is with my viewBox (i think) - can you expand the example to include at least one other path so i can see the diff?

Comment: doesn't make any difference, you can add any path you like to the set http://jsfiddle.net/LN23r/47/

Comment: sorry, i tried to add a path element, but get this http://jsfiddle.net/aqoon/LN23r/48/ why is it covering the viewBox?

Comment: that's another transform issue (see above). The trapezoid's original coordinates are on the scale of 100, and those of the "G" path are on the scale of 1.

Comment: i really can't see from the path where the scale figure comes from; when inspecting the element in inkscape and by browsing the source. i drew the path, by tracing the top trapezoid in inkscape and taking the 'd' data